# How to fix error - <Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'string'>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

While writing a below code in **react typescript** I am facing error **"Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'string'"**. Could you please help to resolve the issue.

```
<!-- Code start from here -->

import { useRef, useState } from "react"

const UseRefMethod = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("Prabhjot")
    const checkInfo = useRef("")
    const reset = () => {
        setName("")
        checkInfo.current.focus()
    }
    console.log(checkInfo)
    return(
        <>
        {name}
        <input ref={"checkInfo"} type="text" value={name} onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)}></input>
        <button onClick={reset}>Reset</button>
        </>
    )
}
export default UseRefMethod
<!-- Code end here -->

I tried using some hacks like <type:string> and many more however, not able to resolve the issue.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be the passing of string value as a ref to the input element instead of the actual ref object.

Specify the type as HTMLInputElement

```
const checkInfo = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)
```

Then try to access the focus method using the current

```
    checkInfo.current?.focus()
```